# Advice for Deep Learning on a laptop without a dedicated GPU

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow

My laptop has a 16gb ram, ryzen 7 processor, ssd etc. But it doesn't have an nvidia gpu. It is said that one can train models on the cloud but for 'inference' the physical laptop should have at least a gtx 1050, so I want to know if the 'inferencing' work is possible say for tensorflow utilizing only the ryzen 7 cpu? If not, is there any alternative to this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use tensorflow-cpu to either train or use models using TensorFlow-CPU:

```
pip install tensorflow-cpu
```

The best solution is to test tensorflow-cpu and see if it is working well for training. Normally, the performance of Ryzen 7 is quite good (see computation comparison between Ryzen7 and GTX 1050), even if it is not a GPU, so it should be ok also for training.

Note: it depends on the model size. If your model is more than 5Gb, the training might be too long.

Comment: Does it answer your question? If not, please let me know.